# Running some performance Tests using Python on Azure

Tags: python, azure, performance-testing

I'm running some performance tests using multimechanize python in order to test some webservices, during the tests I saw some errors reported by multimech that says

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /XXXX/XXXXXXX (Caused by : [Errno -2] Name or service not known)

could this be an issue with the Azure servers?